# @Transactional in unit test prevents @PostLoad from being invoked

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, unit-testing, jpa

I have the following test:

```
public class Book
{
     public boolean postLoadInvoked;
     @PostLoad
     private void onPostLoad()
     {
         postLoadInvoked = true;
     }
}

public class MyIntegrationTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest
{
     @Autowired
     private BookDAO bookDAO;

     @Test
     public void loadBooks()
     {
          Book book = bookDAO.findOne(...);
          assertTrue(book.postLoadInvoked);
     }  
}
```

This test passes as-is, but if I add the `@Transactional` annotations to the test class, it fails:

```
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true)
public class MyIntegrationTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest
```

Why does configuring the test with `@Transactional` affect the JPA callback methods?

***EDIT***

The DAO is just a Spring Data repository, so has no logic:

```
public interface BookDAO extends
   JpaRepository<Book, Long>, 
   QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Book> {}
```

The transaction manager also has a standard configuration:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.mangofactory.example</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="spring-test" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Can you add the bookDao code and the configuration of the transactionManager?

Comment: @gkamal Sure, Updated with more configuration.

Comment: Your @PostLoad method won't compile... it doesn't have a return type.  Are you sure the test ran after this change was compiled?

Comment: @jordan002 Good catch - thanks.  But that was just a typo in this post.  Yes, the tests definitely run.  I'm having the same issue in about a dozen integration tests in my project.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the spring version is that you are using or if AbstractIntegrationTest is extending something, but one thing to check is that in your hierarchy your tests should extend some abstract transactional context aware spring test class.

The classes that I'm thinking about:

```
org.springframework.test.AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests
org.springframework.test.AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests
```

or some jUnit flavor (depending on the version that you are using):

```
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests
org.springframework.test.context.junit38.AbstractTransactionalJUnit38SpringContextTests
```

Answer (score 0):

I could think of two reasons:

1. `@PostLoad` is only executed after the transaction is committed. Unlikely.
2. How did you enable transactions? Did you specify `proxyTargetClass = true`? Otherwise, you can get weird behavior.